# Spring bean properties of imported Jar are overridden by application bean definition

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a class with same name in the imported jar file.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "queues")
public class QueueProperties {
String queuename;
String queuemanager;
//Rest code
}
```

The same class with the same properties also there in the jar file.

I have given bean definition in my configuration file for the jar bean.

```
@Bean
public com.jar.class.path getQueueProperties() {
    return new com.jar.class.path.QueueProperties();
}
```

But when the application started it is using the properties of my bean class instead of the properties defined for jar class bean.

Property values are kept in application.yml file.

```
queue:
  queueManager: 'queuemanager'
  queuename: 'queuename'

jar:
 class: 
   queue:
     queueManager: 'queuemanager'
     queuename: 'queuename'
```

I want to use properties defined in yml for jar file bean. Could there be any solution around this?

Comment: You should not use @Configuration as a regular bean. They are created earlier in Spring context initialization, you may have unexpected behavior like AOP features are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Spring profile.

```
queue:
  queueManager: 'queuemanager'
  queuename: 'queuename'
---
spring:
  profiles: jar
queue:
  queueManager: 'queuemanager'
  queuename: 'queuename'
```

You can use --spring.profiles.active=jar on command line to use your jar profile.

You should not use configuration as normal beans, do this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "queue")
    public com.jar.class.path getQueueProperties() {
        return new com.jar.class.path.QueueProperties();
    }

}

public class QueueProperties {
    String queuename;
    String queuemanager;
    //Rest code
}
```

Comment: I want to use properties of my current application yml file. I'm using these properties in my application. I need jar file properties, when method of a class inside the jar is invoked then bean queueProperties (this is a dependency in the jar class also) should be initialised with jar properties.